# How to remove all duplicate lists and lists that are subset of other lists from an array of lists?

Tags: python, list, set, subset

I am given a list of lists. I have to remove from that list of lists, lists that are full subsets of any other list in that list of lists and lists that are equal to any other list in that list of lists.

For example if my list is given as

```
A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4], [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

The output should be

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

My code is as follows:

```
w=len(A)
sol=[]
for i in range (0,w-1):
    for j in range (1,w):
        ret=all(elem in A[i] for elem in A[j])
        if ret:
            if not(A[i] in sol):
                sol.append(A[i])
        else:
            ret=all(elem in A[j] for elem in A[i])
            if ret:
                if not(A[j] in sol):
                    sol.append(A[j])
```

I am getting output as

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4], [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Where am I making mistake?

If there is any other way for this task, you may share it.

Comment: Can you post your desired output??

Comment: What's expected for [[1, 2], [2, 1]]?

Comment: @Wonka It's there.

Answer (score 1):

In `ret=all(elem in A[i] for elem in A[j])`, you are comparing A[i] = [1,4] and A[j] = [1, 4] then ret returned True.

So changing range of j will work.

```
# for j in range (1,w): # before

for j in range (i+1,w): # after
    ...
```

Edited

```
A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4], [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 6]]
w = len(A)
sol = []

# check wheter A[i] is subset of A[j] or not
for i in range(0, w):
    for j in range(i+1, w):
        ret = all(elem in A[j] for elem in A[i])  # note order: j, i
        if ret:  # A[i] is subset of A[j]
            break

    else:  # A[i] is not subset for all A[j]
        sol.append(A[i])
```

Comment: That's right, but with your aforesaid change if I add [1, 2, 3, 6] to list A, it produces wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

If elements in each sublist are unique, you can use `sets`

```py
A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4], [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]

B = [ set(l) for l in A]

result = []
for candidate in B:
    if any([candidate.issubset(s) for s in B if s != candidate]):
        # Skip subset of any other sublist
        continue
    elif list(candidate) in result:
        # Skip sublists that are already in the result
        continue
    else:
        result.append(list(candidate))
print(result)
```